# Access token for google classroom API says it authorized classroom api but rest api returns request is missing credentials

Tags: react-native, oauth, google-apis-explorer, google-classroom

I have a react-native app that signs users in by using the firebase web SDK. The app successfully signs users in, and when signing in, users are prompted to authorize the google classroom api using these scopes:
`['profile', 'email', "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly"]`

After successfully authenticating, users are redirected to a dashboard. In this dashboard, I want to display their google classrooms that they are enrolled in. I store the access token with firebase, but when I go to fetch from the google classroom rest api, I get an error saying that the request is missing credentials.

I have tried including the access token in both the header and the url directly.

How I sign my users in:

(onSignIn manually logs in the user to firebase using the firebase manual code that they provided)

```
googleAuth = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await Expo.Google.logInAsync({
        iosClientId : "MY IOS CLIENT ID IS ACTUALLY SET IN MY CODE",
        scopes : ['profile', 'email', "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly"],
        behavior : 'web'
      })

      if(result.type === 'success') {
        this.onSignIn(result)
        console.log(result)
      }
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.log("ERROR", e)
    }
  }
```

Once routed to the dashboard:

```
listCourses = async (auth) => {
    if(firebase.auth().currentUser) {

      const token = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()
      .then(tkn => {
        return tkn
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        return undefined;
      })

      if(token) {
        fetch("https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses?accessToken=" + token, {
          method : "GET",
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res)
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

What I expected was to get a list of classes, similar to what happened when I authenticated using the Oauth2.0 client on the google classroom rest API (I received a 200 request with the courses in an array)
What actually happened is I received this error:

```
401 error
\"message\": \"Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.\",
"url": "https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses?accessToken=MY ACTUAL ACCESS TOKEN",
```

Comment: Can you run through authentication using the [Oauth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground)? It may be instructive for you.

Answer (score 0):

An ID token and an access token are different things. The ID token contains user information in JWT format, while an access token is an opaque string you send along with future request. More information about Firebase Login with Google is available here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin

Comment: Thank you Eric. I have since figured that out which was a dumb mistake on my part. I have access to the access token in the google sign in, but when I log the user into firebase, how do I get access to that same access token in the firebase auth?